# Calculate the volume $λ_3(A)$ of $A := \{ (x, y, z) ∈\mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 ≤ y^2 + z^2 ≤ 1\} $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, definite-integrals, volume

I have a lot of problems with exercises where I must calculate the Volume of a set using integrals.

Here an example:

Le the set $A$ be $A := \{ (x, y, z) ∈\mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 ≤ y^2 + z^2 ≤ 1\} $. Calculate its volume $λ_3(A)$.

So what I thought is to doing something like this:

$λ_3(A)=λ_3(A_1)-λ_3(A_2)$

Where $A_1 := \{ (x, y, z) ∈\mathbb{R}^3 : y^2 + z^2 ≤ 1\}$ and $A_2 := \{ (x, y, z) ∈\mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 ≤ y^2 + z^2 \}$

But here comes my problem for every exercise like this: I dont know how to find the limits of my triple integral.

Can someone help me?

Comment: $A_2$ is not a subset of $A_1.$ So that won't work..

Comment: $-1\le x\le 1$ and $y=r\cos t,z=r\sin t$ with $|x|\le r\le1,0\le t<2\pi.$

Comment: @AnneBauval and how do you come to this?

Comment: how you thought of that

Comment: $y^2+z^2$ made me think of polar coordinates

Comment: and how do I use what you stated for solving mz coordinates? Is there a way without polar coordinates?

Comment: $\iiint_Adxdydz=\int_{-1}^1\left(\iint_{|x|\le r\le1,0\le t<2\pi}rdrdt\right)dx=4\pi\int_0^1\left(\int_x^1rdr\right)dx=\dots.$ There are certainly other ways but that one seems the simplest.

Comment: Can you explain it to me without using polar coordinates? I'm new to this topic and polar coordinates only confuse me more

Comment: $\iiint_Adxdydz=\int_{-1}^1C(x)dx$ where $C(x)=\iint_{x^2\le y^2+z^2\le1}dydz=\pi(1-x^2)$ (area of an annulus).

Answer (score 1):

In cylindrical coordinates with $x$ as the height axis the region becomes
$$\{(x,r,\theta)\in\mathbb R^3:x^2\le r^2\le1\}$$
This can be simplified a bit since $r$ is positive:
$$\{(x,r,\theta)\in\mathbb R^3:|x|\le r\le1\}$$
The region is a cylinder with radius $1$ and height $2$, minus two right circular cones with base radius $1$ and height $1$. The volume is thus
$$\pi\cdot2-2\cdot\frac13\pi\cdot1=\frac43\pi$$
We can check this answer by integrating in the aforementioned cylindrical coordinates:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_{-r}^r1\cdot r\,dx\,dr\,d\theta$$
$$=2\pi\int_0^12r^2\,dr=4\pi[r^3/3]_0^1=\frac{4\pi}3$$

Answer (score 0):

$\iiint_Adxdydz=\int_{-1}^1C(x)dx$ where $C(x)=\iint_{x^2\le y^2+z^2\le1}dydz=\pi(1-x^2)$ ([area of an annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics)#Area)).

Hence
$$\lambda_3(A)=\pi\int_{-1}^1(1-x^2)dx=\pi\left[x-\frac{x^3}3\right]_{-1}^1=\frac{4\pi}3.$$

Comment: Could you write $C(x)$ but with the limits for every integrals?

Comment: $C(x)$ is the difference of the area of two discs. For the area of a disc, see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44631